# How to use a different distance method (simpson) in pvclust

Tags: similarity, pvclust

I am trying to run function pvclust, but using simpson dissimilarities instead using one of the default distances. Can I include a distance function inside the pvclust (method.dist). I already have my simpson dissimilarity intex as a dist. object from the package betapart, and that is the one that I want to use in pvclust.

Thanks!